# What to do with a question that's directly addressed to a customer service department?

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users

I saw this post earlier today:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805476/need-to-retrieve-an-already-created-api-related-key

[image]

What is the best way to deal with it? Is there any link to explain Stack Overflow to them?

Comment: It's garbage.  Close voted.

Comment: See also [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) (which is even a FAQ)

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for that link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any link to explain SO to them?

Yes.  Use the following meta FAQ [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)